# nodejs where declare variable using require

Tags: node.js

i would to know what's the best way between these two codes:

```
module.exports = function(){

    require('fs').readFile..
       crequire('./sockets.js').clients..
       ...

};
```

second:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var clients = require('./sockets.js').clients;

module.exports = function(){


    fs.readFile...
       clients...

}
```

I search the best way to optimize.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From performance point of view there is no difference, because `require` is cached after first call. But still I think that the code is more readable when you declare imports at the begining of the script. Thus the second version is prefered, imho.

Comment: yes you're right, but i think that for the performance, the first version is faster because variables are the basis of storage, so the second use this base, but there are like a route who slowing. But using the first version, it costs more memory. But .. is negligible.

Comment: @CydGy Yes, of course. But there's no point in optimizing this kind of almost invisible differences. :) It's a waste of time. :)