# Node.js : module exports, only object

Tags: node.js

I don't understand why only object are nice exported. Look that:

**first file**

```
var a = exports.a = {};
var b = exports.b = 0;

exports.xxxxx = function(){

    a.hello = 'help';
    b = 104;

};
```

**second file**

```
var a = require('firstfile').a;
var b = require('firstfile').b;

module.exports = function(){

    console.log(a); // {hello:'help'}
    console.log(b); // 0

};
```

Why ?

and the solution for exports b is do like that:

**first file:**

```
...
a.hello = 'help';
exports.b = 104; // (add exports)
...
```

**second file:**

```
...
var b = require('firstfile');
...
console.log(b.b); // 104
```

Why?

**EDIT**

I think I understood.

The variable a take just a reference!
I will explain to someone who does not understand:

- when the first file is read, `a = {}, b = 0`
- when we change b, b as been changed, but NOT the module (the exports) !!
- this is normal that with `exports.b = 104` // we change the value of the module! who is required.

Now, why object are different ?

- because when the file 2 is executed. (executed once), the value of a = {}.
- but it displays {xxx:xxx}
- this is because the value of a when the file is executed is not {}, but a reference of this object.
- So, when we need to take this object, we search all reference.

*it is important to remember two things:*

- modules required out of a function are read once! Need to require in the function for see changes.
- objects stock reference.

Bye!
Hope this help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `0` to `exports.b`, it is essentially assigned as a constant value.  You can update the value pointed to by the `b` variable, but it won't be re-exported.

For instance, I've modified what you posted slightly by adding a `getB` function:

```
var a = exports.a = {};
var b = exports.b = 0;

exports.xxxxx = function(){

    a.hello = 'help';
    b = 104;

};

exports.getB = function() { return b; };
```

Then, you can see what I mean by playing around with this file in REPL:

```
> var example = require('./example.js');
undefined
> example
{ a: {},
  b: 0,
  xxxxx: [Function],
  getB: [Function] }
> example.xxxxx()
undefined
> example.getB()
104
> example.b
0
>
```

edit: your comment about references is somewhat correct.  When you initially say

```
var b = exports.b = 0;
```

You are saying two variables point to the same value.  This is different than two variables pointing to the same reference (an object, as you've done with `a`).  When you modify one value, the other value is not modified.  In other words, when you change the value of 0 to 1, you don't want every instance of `0` in your code to then also be `1`. That wouldn't be good.

If you want `b` to be a value and to get updated every time you modify that value, you should reassign `exports.b`.  This is part of why you'll see most code as one object being exported... then, your export is treated like a reference and all your `b`'s are updated as expected.

Comment: yes, that's what i understand was succeful. But your function getB is very good! it avoids to re-exports eatch time. Thank you! i did not know

Comment: So do you think that stock require module (e.g "fs") out of the function is better for the performance ? I heard that module are catched, so don't need to stock in a variable and cluttering the memory? look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636599/nodejs-where-declare-variable-using-require

Comment: Those modules are cached by NodeJS. You most likely won't see a difference in performance because the initialization is done once. The question is whether you want to require those modules on every function call if you do it in a function. I wouldn't.  Your entire file will already be wrapped in a function.

Comment: humm i understand but not the end: "Your entire file will already be wrapped in a function" (i'm french). (i edited my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636599/nodejs-where-declare-variable-using-require) thanks! (i know that we can say that this is the tiny optimization, but i'd rather go with a good foundation. Thank you.